# Unit Testing Angular app in production controller is so much complex can figure out how to do that

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi need to write unit test for my angular application that already build but problem is that controller having so many dependency i can't figure out how to go ahead.

Here is signature of the controller

```
angular.controller('MainController', [
    '$log',
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    'l10nModel',
    'authModel',
    'authService',
    'permissionModel',
    'screenConfigurationModel',
    'userModel',
    'events',
    'roles',
    'session',
    '$q',
    '$window',
    'AUTH_EVENTS',
    '$timeout',
    'chatModel',
    'emailModel',
    'mobileClientCheckerService',
    '$rootScope',
    '$http',
    '$modal',
    function ($log, $scope, $state, l10nModel, authModel, authService, permissionModel, screenConfigurationModel, userModel, events, roles, session, $q, $window, AUTH_EVENTS, $timeout, chatModel, emailModel, mobileClientCheckerService, $rootScope, $http, $modal) {

    }
]);
```

Hi i have imported all required module but still i am not clear how to provide dependency

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to import the definitions in the right order so for example if you have a domain layer that is referred by services and controllers that in turn is referring services then you need to import in the following way

```
beforeEach(module("models")); // is dependent on no one
beforeEach(module("services")); // is dependent on models
beforeEach(module("controllers")); // is dependent on both services
```

after that you need to inject the exact controllers/services etc.. that you need for testing.

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_myService_) {
    myService = _myService_;
}));

it('test something',function(){
   expect(myService.add(1,2)).toBe(3)
})
```

Also in the config file you need to point out your applications js files and also where to find the tests

And corresponding example for controller would be

```
var scope;
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
   scope : $rootScope.new();
   $controller('YourCtrl',
            {$scope: scope, $location: mock1, restService: mock2...});
}))
```

And for the test

```
it('test controller',function(){
   scope.add({name : 'test'});
   expect(scope.items.length).toBe(1)
});
```

Comment: Hi i have imported all required module but still i am not clear how to provide dependency

Comment: please have a look at my updated answer.. by using $controller you can provide your own mocks of your dependencies... The idea is just to test controller behaviour so its ok to send in mocks for most dependencies

Comment: Hey Chris still i can't get you my controller is so long https://jsfiddle.net/ashok_patidar1/2p2huesx/

Comment: My project is very big and it's already developed by some one else i m just new to that but i have been told to write unit test case for that but i can't figure out how to start for small controller i am able to test as angular help provided https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-a-controller

Comment: What you gave an example on was not a small control. It was the mother of all controls. Usually its not good to have that many dependencies.. I will give you an example how to make your controller work below but you need to figure out what to test...  Usually I do unit tests for services and protractor tests if I need a higher level...

Comment: So add unit tests for your services first and think long and hard if you really need controller tests.. If there is a lot of logic in the controller then thats a major design flaw, usally, not always :)

Comment: I had a look on your code and it seems most things happen on emitted events. Whats interesting for you to tests is branching logic if/ else. So in a test, try doing for example  scope.$emit(AUTH_EVENTS.LOGOUT_SUCCESS) and try creating a mock of authService to guarentee you can hit both if and else

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is more that you need to find out WHAT to test. Is it a behaviour or parsing or what?  Just saying to someone add a few unit tests isn't very nice. I think you should go back and ask what is important that it works. Never add a few tests just because..

```
var scope;
var mockState = {};
var l10nModelMock = {};

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope){
   scope : $rootScope.new();
   $controller('MainController',
        {$scope: scope, $state: mockState, l10nModel : l10nModelMock... });
}))
```

Comment: Hey i want to discuss with you is there any way to connect with you because as of now i am very new to writing the unit test from where i have to get start. i have done small poc where i have seen small small program and i am able to run that but individual.

Comment: Sure try adding me on chat on noringc@gmail.com  /Chris

Comment: Hey i agree that i have to start unit test from services. this is my service https://jsfiddle.net/ashok_patidar1/5xy9megg/ when i do unit test it's giving me below error

Comment: Hey i agree that i have to start unit test from services.service https://jsfiddle.net/ashok_patidar1/5xy9megg/ when i do unit test it's giving me  error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userServiceProvider <- userSer
vice http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=userServiceProvider
%20%3C-%20userService describe('securityModule Service', function()

Comment: Hi i need your help to implement testing in my project